# How to pass id from jquery datatable to a other jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I want to pass a Id from jquery datatable to a other jquery function.

Here is the jquery function that I want to pass a Id too

```
   $("#makeEditable").on('mousedown.save', "i.save.material-icons", function (e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/gestiondeubicaciones/Editar',
                        data: { id: 3 }, /* How to pass  id here???*/
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {

                        }
                    });
                    $(this).text("edit").removeClass().addClass("edit material-icons");
                    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':last');//.not(':first');

                    $.each($tds, function (i, el) {
                        var txt = $(this).find("input").val()
                        $(this).html(txt);
                    });
                });
```

To be more specific I want to replace 3 with a variable

```
                    data: { id: 3 }, /* How to pass  id here???*/
```

Here is my datatble code

```
var table;
            table = $('#makeEditable').DataTable({
                rowReorder: {
                    selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
                },
                responsive: true,
                ajax: "/gestiondeubicaciones/GetUbicaciones",
                columns: [
                    { data: "armario" },
                    { data: "cajon" },
                    {
                        data: "ubicacion_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="popup-edit"><i id="editSave" class="edit material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>' +
                                '<a class="popup-delete" href="#" onclick="DeleteData(' + data + ');" title="Eliminar"><i class="delete material-icons">delete</i></a>'; 
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Do be more specific I want to pass data to the jquery function.

```
 function (data) {
                                return '<a class="popup-edit"><i id="editSave" class="edit material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>'
```

How can I pass data from jquery datatable to the jquery function. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In your pass Id (ubicacion_id) from your datatabe then-

```
{
    data: "ubicacion_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
    return '<a class="popup-edit"><i id="editSave"  data-id="' + data + '" class="edit material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>'; 
  }
```

2.In your jquery click event-

```
data: { id: $(this).attr("data-id") },
```

OR

1.In your pass Id (ubicacion_id) from your datatabe then-

```
{
    data: "ubicacion_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
    return '<a class="popup-edit"><i id="editSave" onmousedown="EditData(' + data + ');" class="edit material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>'; 
  }// you can onclick rather than onmousedown event
```

2.In your jquery click event-

```
function EditData(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/gestiondeubicaciones/Editar',
        data: { id: id },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
    $(this).text("edit").removeClass().addClass("edit material-icons");
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':last');//.not(':first');

    $.each($tds, function (i, el) {
        var txt = $(this).find("input").val()
        $(this).html(txt);
    });
}
```

if you want to get any or all data in current `row` in datatable, then-

```
{ "width": "50px", "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<a class="popup-edit"><i id="editSave" onmousedown="EditData(' + row.ubicacion_id + ');" class="edit material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>'; }
```

Comment: Your solution works and answers my question however I realize that I should pass the complete model and not just the id how can I pass armario and cajon as well? It would be appreciated. I have approved you answer since it answered the question I asked. Thank you.

Comment: `{
  "width": "50px", "render": function (data, type, row) {
 return "<a href='#' class='popup' onclick=Delete('" + row.proveedor_id + "'); title='Eliminar'><i class='material-icons'></i>delete</a>";
},`  row= your current row in datatable.